# Inno Setup: powershell script call always returns 2

Tags: powershell, cmd, installation, inno-setup

I want to launch a powershell script from Inno setup, and it always returns 2 (system cannot find the file specified). I tried in many ways the return code is always 2.

```
try
    ExtractTemporaryFile( 'GetOlderVersionUninstallString.ps1' );    
  except
    ShowExceptionMessage();
  end;

  TempDir := ExpandConstant('{tmp}');
  //v1
  ShellExec('open' ,'cmd /c powershell.exe', ' -executionpolicy bypass ".\GetOlderVersionUninstallString.ps1"', TempDir , SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);
  MsgBox('Return code: ' + IntToStr( ErrorCode ), mbConfirmation, MB_OK);
  //v2
  Exec('powershell.exe', '-noexit -noninteractive -executionpolicy bypass "' + TempDir + '\GetOlderVersionUninstallString.ps1"', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);
  MsgBox('Return code: ' + IntToStr( ErrorCode ), mbConfirmation, MB_OK);
```

Comment: You are trying to execute `cmd /c powershell.exe` but you certainly wanted to execute only `cmd`. But anyway, better execute directly `powershell.exe` without command line interpreter.

Comment: So v2 is better then v1. But when I try to run a simple calc.exe the return code is 2. So I don't think there is a problem with the script itself. Operating system: Windows Server 2008R2

Comment: It sounds like the `powershell.exe` doesn't add itself to the path environment and so you'll need to specify the absolute path to it. In all cases you should check whether PowerShell is installed before you attempt to run your script, so I think that when you'll be working on that, you can make also a function to get the path to the `powershell.exe`.

Comment: The powershell window is now shown but it say: The term ' cmd' is not recognized...

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a bit confused now. With my first comment I meant that you should execute only `cmd` and the rest (`/c powershell.exe`) put into the next parameter. Or, execute directly `powershell` as you do in your second code example and which seems that would require the absolute path.

Comment: The absolute path is the answer. And you have to set then environmental variables yourself.
Thanks :)